# more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression in postgreSql query with IN clause

Tags: postgresql, switch-statement, in-clause

I am facing an issue with the query in postgreSql. Below is the query.

```
UPDATE t_e20so1_fieldrulethen AS fthen 
SET    c_thenfieldid = t1.c_fieldschemaid 
FROM   t_sys_fieldschema AS t1 
WHERE  fthen.c_lyrathenfieldid = t1.c_lyraid 
   AND fthen.c_rulefor = 5 
   AND t1.c_fieldtype = 18 
   AND t1.c_tablegroupsid IN ( 
       CASE 
         WHEN fthen.c_iffieldid = t1.c_id THEN (SELECT 
         c_targettableid 
         FROM t_sys_tablegroups 
         WHERE c_parentid = 'c0b2f85c-bc93-466b-a54d-b1330440db98') 
         ELSE (SELECT c_targettableid 
               FROM   t_sys_tablegroups 
               WHERE  c_parentid = 
                      'c0b2f85c-bc93-466b-a54d-b1330440db98') 
       END );
```

As per above query, i am updating `t_e20so1_fieldrulethen` table from `t_sys_fieldschema`. One of the conditions to check is `t_sys_fieldschema.c_tablegroupsid` should be having specific values which are in and I am fetching them from table `t_sys_tablegroups`.

Above query gives me error as shown below:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

Here, if I remove case from the query (below is what I mean) it works properly.

```
UPDATE t_e20so1_fieldrulethen AS fthen 
SET    c_thenfieldid = t1.c_fieldschemaid 
FROM   t_sys_fieldschema AS t1 
WHERE  fthen.c_lyrathenfieldid = t1.c_lyraid 
   AND fthen.c_rulefor = 5 
   AND t1.c_fieldtype = 18 
   AND t1.c_tablegroupsid IN (SELECT c_targettableid 
                              FROM   t_sys_tablegroups 
                              WHERE 
           c_parentid = 'c0b2f85c-bc93-466b-a54d-b1330440db98')
```

**Now I have only one select query in the "IN" clause.**

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: Above is the wrong query (first one) and I need to figure out how to put a condition in "IN" clause in the correct way.

Comment: Unrelated but may be important - for me, both statements in the case looks exactly same for WHEN and for ELSE.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek exactly, only one select statement does not give an error but the data. But when I use two statements in the "IN" clause it gives mentioned error.

Comment: I've rechekd this CASE conditions. In one Case you return Two separate lists one for fthen.c_iffieldid = t1.c_id  and second for ELSE. And for IN you can have only one list. For future stop using nested selects for IN  clasue and retrurnig results it is very, very bad practise.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked that kind of case statement(two nested selects) - and it cannot be done that way. You generate two separate lists in one CASE.
One list for all records where fthen.c_iffieldid = t1.c_id and the other for ELSE statement.

As I wrote many times never use nested selects in "IN" clause. It is killing performance and causing many problems. Use "EXISTS".
As your CASE seems to be redundant (both WHEN and ELSE returns same value) change it that way and it will be faster.

```
UPDATE t_e20so1_fieldrulethen AS fthen 
   SET c_thenfieldid = t1.c_fieldschemaid 
  FROM t_sys_fieldschema AS t1 
 WHERE fthen.c_lyrathenfieldid = t1.c_lyraid 
   AND fthen.c_rulefor = 5 
   AND t1.c_fieldtype = 18 
   AND exists (select from t_sys_tablegroups t2 
                where t1.c_tablegroupsid=t2.c_targettableid
                  and  c_parentid = 'c0b2f85c-bc93-466b-a54d-b1330440db98');
```